# Write elements from multiple Arraylists to txt file in specific order

Tags: java, arraylist

Doing an assignment and I have tried to write a code for a button to generate a report in the form of a txt file. I have made ArrayLists for each piece of information needed in the report but haven't set an initial size. I have this snippet of code which I have written but i'm not extremely knowledgeable in Java.

```
    File newTextFile = new File("D:/Report.txt");
             FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
             int i=0;
             for(int i=0; i<=FirstName.size(); i++;){
                 fw.write(FirstName.get(i));
                 fw.write(LastName.get(i));
                 fw.write(DOB.get(i));
                 fw.write(Gender.get(i));
                 fw.write(Email.get(i));
                 fw.write(Address.get(i));
                 fw.write(Number.get(i));
                 fw.write(Attending.get(i));
             }
             int x=0;
             if(InternationalCheck.get(x) == "yes"){
                 int y=0;
                 fw.write(Nationality.get(x));
                 x++;
             }
             int DomesticPrice = 50;
             int InternationalPrice = 150;
             int sum = (DomesticCheck.size()*DomesticPrice)+(InternationalCheck.size()*InternationalPrice);
             String sum1 = ""+sum;
             String Total = "The total revenue is:";
             fw.write(Total);
             fw.write(sum1);
             fw.close();
```

I keep getting IndexOutOfBoundsException Errors and can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include the exception stack-trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
  for(int i=0; i<=FirstName.size(); i++;){
```

With using `<` instead of `<=` like below:

```
 for(int i=0; i<FirstName.size(); i++){
```

Comment: Thank you so much can't believe it was that simple I feel stupid